# Continue Mule (3.3) flow even after exceptions

Tags: exception, error-handling, esb, mule

Mule 3.3.0
I have a flow that splits a payload.
Then each item goes through a custom transformer which migh throw an exception if item is malformed.
I have a catch exception strategy to log the error item to file.
I would like the flow to continue processing rest of items, which as far as I know, should be the expected behaviour.
The problem is that the flow stops.

I'm attaching a simple test flow allong with a simple test file.
The file is a csv file with 2 lines, each line with 3 fields.
Im using groovy scripts to, first split file into lines, then each line into fields.
I'm also using a groovy script to simulate an exception when a field is malformed.  In this case if the field is the word "goodbye" it will throw a RuntimeException.
If you test this flow you will see that the rest of the fields after the exception won't get processed (i.e. logged in this case).
In this particulare example, the catch exception stragegy won't even fire.

Input File:

```
hello,cruel,world
goodbye,cruel,world
```

TestFlow

[image: TestFlow]

TestCase.mflow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd ">

    <file:connector name="inputFileConnector" autoDelete="true"
        streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" fileAge="60000"
         readFromDirectory="#{systemProperties['user.home']}"/>
    <catch-exception-strategy name="Catch_Exception_Strategy">
        <logger message="!!!!! Exception Handler !!!!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>

    <flow name="TestCaseFlow1" doc:name="TestCaseFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="#{systemProperties['user.home']}"
            responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Input File" fileAge="100" connector-ref="inputFileConnector">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="input.csv"
                caseSensitive="false" />
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <scripting:text><![CDATA[return payload.split('\n');]]></scripting:text>
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <scripting:text><![CDATA[return payload.split(',');]]></scripting:text>
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <scripting:text><![CDATA[if (payload.equals('goodbye')) {
                            throw new java.lang.RuntimeException('Dang!');
                        }
                        return payload]]></scripting:text>
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <logger message=">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Is your payload a collection of objects? Can you post your config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do first is separate your main flow. After every `collection-splitter` put a JMS or VM `outbound-endpoint`, this way every message will have its own thread and if one fails the others will not be affected.

```
<flow name="flow1">
  <file:inbound-endpoint path="#{systemProperties['user.home']}"
      responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Input File" fileAge="100" connector-ref="inputFileConnector">
      <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="input.csv"
      caseSensitive="false" />
  </file:inbound-endpoint>
  <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
  <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
      <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
      <scripting:text><![CDATA[return payload.split('\n');]]></scripting:text>
      </scripting:script>
  </scripting:component>
  <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
  <vm:outbound-endpoint path="toFlow2"/>
</flow>

 <flow name="flow2">
  <vm:inbound-endpoint path="toFlow2"/>
  <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
      <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
      <scripting:text><![CDATA[return payload.split(',');]]></scripting:text>
      </scripting:script>
  </scripting:component>
  <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
  <vm:outbound-endpoint path="toFlow3"/>
</flow>

 <flow name="flow3">
  <vm:inbound-endpoint path="toFlow3"/>
  <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
      <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
      <scripting:text><![CDATA[if (payload.equals('goodbye')) {
              throw new java.lang.RuntimeException('Dang!');
          }
          return payload]]></scripting:text>
      </scripting:script>
  </scripting:component>
  <logger message=">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot Daniel.  I just hope Mule documentation was better.